# How to cancel a dialog in the bot framework?

Tags: botframework

I am trying to keep a user of my bot busy when waiting on a particularly slow api. I forward the user to a new dialog and supply a cancellation token to cancel the dialog once the api has returned my result.

I expected the code below to quit the stallUntilCompletedDialog when I invoke Cancel() on the cancellation token

```
public async Task ResumeAfterFirstDialog(IDialogContext context,
                                         IAwaitable<API.Models.Request> result)
{
    var requestData = await result;
    var response = new API.Models.Response();
    var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        response = await _slowApi.CallApi(requestData, accessToken);

        cancellationToken.Cancel();
    });

    var stallUntilCompletedDialog = new StallUntilCompletedDialog<ApiResponse>();
    await context.Forward(stallUntilCompletedDialog, 
                          ResumeAfterCompletedDialog, 
                          result, 
                          cancellationToken.Token);
}
```

ResumeAfterCompletedDialog never starts and I am stuck in the stalling dialog.
How can I accomplish that the dialog quits when the api responds, and how do I make the api response available in my ResumeAfterCompletedDialog?

Comment: `ResumeAfterCompletedDialog never starts and I am stuck in the stalling dialog` Does it throw any exception?

Comment: No exception whatsoever. I did some more investigation, and what I think is happening is the following. Task.Run creates a new instance of my rootDialog and therefore everything I do in the task.Run block has no influence on the first instance, i.e. the one belonging to the main thread. Any idea how I should run a task that waits for the api to responds, and at the same time entertain the user with some more dialog?

Comment: Instead of calling `cancellationToken.Cancel()` try calling `Context.Done(true)` the true value can vary depending on if you are returning something from your dialog

Comment: The problem is that the stallUntilCompletedDialog doesn't know when the slow api has returned a value. So I don't know when to call context.Done() within the new dialog. Or are you saying I can call context.Done() in the Task.Run, and it will stop the stalling dialog?

Comment: yes, this will be a problem.  You will not be able to do it this way unless you manually remove the stall dialog from the stack.  you may want to rethink this design.  This may be an appropriate use for [continuations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks#passing-data-to-a-continuation)